Importing Complex Docx Content (Equations, Symbols, Images, Multilingual Text) into SunEditor
I am working on integrating complex .docx files into a web application using SunEditor. These documents are created in Microsoft Office 2010 and contain equations, symbols, images, as well as text in both Bengali and English. When I try to copy the content from the .docx file and paste it into SunEditor, the formatting breaks—especially for equations, symbols, and images.
I can manually input equations using KaTeX, which is supported as a plugin in SunEditor, but I encounter issues with displaying equations that use a custom Bengali font. Here are the challenges I'm facing:

Equations and Symbols: These do not transfer well when pasted directly into SunEditor. Although I can re-enter equations manually using KaTeX, it does not support the custom Bengali font used in the original document.

Images: These also do not transfer when pasting directly from the .docx file.


Questions:

How can I improve the import process to ensure that equations, symbols, and images from the .docx file are accurately represented in SunEditor?

Is there a way to configure KaTeX (or any other tool within SunEditor) to support custom fonts, specifically Bengali, for equations?
Any guidance or recommendations on how to handle these types of content more effectively in SunEditor would be greatly appreciated!


I am using JavaScript to address this issue, but I am also open to solutions using Python.
